# js does not see the second number

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**If I try to approve bug 11, it approves bug 1.**
Please help solve this problem
bot, does not perceive numbers consisting of two digits at all

```
    client.on('message', async (message, member, channel) => {
    
      if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
      var args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
      const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
      args = args.join(" ");
      let perms = message.member.permissions;
    
      if (command === 'accept') {
        const user = await message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id)
        if (!user.roles.cache.get(ApprovoredRoleID)) return message.reply('Доступно только охотникам за багами')
        if (!args[0]) return message.reply('Укажите Bug-ID')
        var SelectBug = await BugScheme.findOne({ id: args[0] });
        if (!SelectBug) return message.reply('Я не могу найти идентификатор отчета.')
        if (SelectBug.reportStatus != 'none') return message.reply('Этот отчет уже перемещен.')
        var bug = client.channels.cache.get(BugsChannel)
        bug.messages.fetch({around: SelectBug.messageid, limit: 1})
          .then(msg => {
            const fetchedMsg = msg.first();
            fetchedMsg.edit(`**───────────────────**\n<@${SelectBug.owner}> сообщил\n\n**Название:** ${SelectBug.title}\n**Описание:** ${SelectBug.description}\n\nПроверил ${message.author} <:yes:917708321056768000>\nID отчета: **${SelectBug.id}**`);
        });
        SelectBug.reportStatus = 'accept'
        SelectBug.save()
```

[mongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/419K1.png)

Comment: when you do `args = args.join(" ")` you are turning it back into a string; I don't think this is what you want to do

Comment: Instead of putting the picture of compass, just put one sample of data as code here.
Moreover, can you also provide an input to this function (e.g. the discord command)?

Comment: After joining  args.join(""), parse it to integer - parseInt(args). and directly use args instead of args[0]

Comment: Please shorten the code so we can more easily identify the problem

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tZ9c8JQ9 full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are only getting the first character of the string. Remove `args = args.join(" ")` and do this instead:

```js
var SelectBug = await BugScheme.findOne({ id: args.join("") })
```

Comment: C:\Users\gemer\Downloads\discord-bug-trello\index.js:38
    var SelectBug = await BugScheme.findOne({ id: args.join("") })
                                                       ^

TypeError: args.join is not a function

Comment: @flameprofi You haven't removed `args = args.join(" ")`, have you?